# Writing code that doesn't contain Roman Numerals

Tags: java

I am writing code for an assignment an it must follow these guidelines:
/* returns true if s consists only of letters that
     * are also Roman numerals */

I have written code that looks like this:

```
if (!s.contains("I") || !s.contains("V") || !s.contains("X") || 
!s.contains("L") || !s.contains("C") || !s.contains("D") || !s.contains("M") 
|| !s.contains("i") || !s.contains("v") || !s.contains("x") || 
!s.contains("l") || !s.contains("c") || !s.contains("d") || 
!s.contains("m")) {
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

This looks like it would work but it does not. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't use `contains()` for this. Throw away that code and try something else.

Comment: Why do you think that code would work for `iq`?

Comment: revisit your logical operators.  Your code as written will return only return false if it contains all of the roman numerals (uppercase and lowercase...)

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean containsOnlyRomanNumerals(String s) {
  return s.matches("[IVXLCDMivxlcdm]*");
}
```

This should do the trick. The regular expression checks if `s` consists only of the characters in the square brackets.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the characters into a list and check if that list contains the character your checking. This is way cleaner and better maintainable. Now just run the string into a forloop. If you find a character that is roman break and return false..otherwise return true.

```
public static boolean checkRomanNums(String s){
    List<Character> romanNumerials=Arrays.asList('I','V','X','L','C','D','M');
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(romanNumerials.contains(s.charAt(i))){
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: My bad. I thought I would explain it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `return s.matches("(?i)[ivxlcdm]+");`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.